# Counting a Large Amount of Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, counting

So, I have two scripts running in Node.js.

Script A outputs a whole number that is >= 40 and is <= 320.

Script B runs script A millions of times and needs to count how many times each number appears.

What is the best way to go about doing this? There has to be a better solution than typing `let number40 = 0; let number 41 = 0;` all the way up to 320.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having a `map-enum-like` object holding `key` as `number` and as per their occurrences, incrementing their value;

```js
let obj = {};
let numbers = [50, 55, 120, 300, 150, 50, 300, 50];

numbers.forEach(function(num) {
  obj[num] ? ++obj[num] : (obj[num] = 1);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Useing [**`Map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
let myMap = new Map();
let numbers = [50, 55, 120, 300, 150, 50, 300, 50];

numbers.forEach(function(num) {
  let val = myMap.get(num) || 0;
  myMap.set(num, ++val);
});
console.log(myMap);//check browsers console to check the value.
```

Comment: May as well just use a `Map` object.

Comment: I'll try the lower segment. See how that goes.

Comment: Works great. Combined it with a sort function found on another stack overflow answer.